# Is math style's order effecting output?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

In `texdoc unicode-math` sec 5.2, it says

> Note that `bold-style` is independent of `math-style`, although if the former
> is not specified then matching defaults are chosen based on the latter.

It means `bold-style` and `math-style`'s order doesn't decide output. However I did tests below. Here is the main `.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX, bold-style=ISO}
\begin{document}
    $ \symbf{a} $
\end{document}
```

It gives an italic bold "a". When I put `bold-style` before `math-style`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO, math-style=TeX}
\begin{document}
    $ \symbf{a} $
\end{document}
```

It gives an upright bold "a". It makes me confused. Could anyone explain why it behaved like this?

Comment: well I would say that your interpretation is wrong, and that order matters. (keys are normally processed from left to right, so for dependant keys order matters.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but if I use `bold-style=ISO` first, it still doesn't give a ISO style bold letter, or, you means that `math-style=TeX` covers `bold-style=ISO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passage you quote has not the meaning you claim. It means rather that if `bold-style` is not specified, then `math-style` chooses something by default. In fact the code of `unicode-math` contains

```
\__um_keys_choices:nn {math-style}
 {
      {ISO} {
             \unimathsetup { nabla=upright, partial=italic,
              normal-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, sans-style=italic }
            }
      {TeX} {
             \unimathsetup { nabla=upright, partial=italic,
               normal-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX, sans-style=upright }
            }
   {french} {
             \unimathsetup { nabla=upright, partial=upright,
               normal-style=french, bold-style=upright, sans-style=upright }
            }
  {upright} {
             \unimathsetup { nabla=upright, partial=upright,
               normal-style=upright, bold-style=upright, sans-style=upright }
            }
  {literal} {
             \unimathsetup { colon=literal, nabla=literal, partial=literal,
               normal-style=literal, bold-style=literal, sans-style=literal }
            }
 }
```

As options are processed in the order they are given in the code if you want a `bold-style` which so to say "collides" with `math-style` (i.e. does not correspond to the default), you must give `math-style` *first*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solved my problem. By the way, form the source code, I found I can use `normal-style` to set the "normal style", even `texdoc unicode-math` doesn't mention it.